# MBP 2012 restarts at times for no reason

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, crash, kernel-panic

I have this crash coming up lately...any ideas?
FYI, I do have two different RAMs 1x2gb 1x4gb different manufacturer.

```
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 0, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 69874 loops in 1147385509 ticks
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800464aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80044c549f, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000000000009f, CR3: 0x0000000009b97000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff800501cb28, RBX: 0xffffff8015153d80, RCX: 0x00000000000000f6, RDX: 0xffffffffffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff8ceefbb570, RBP: 0xffffff8ceefbbd80, RSI: 0x0000000000000007, RDI: 0xffffff8015711540
R8:  0xffffff8015806800, R9:  0x000005beb8db3a83, R10: 0x0000000000000015, R11: 0x0000000009b97000
R12: 0x00000000a13a59a0, R13: 0xffffff8014fa31c0, R14: 0x0000000000000007, R15: 0x000000000000000b
RFL: 0x0000000000010082, RIP: 0xffffff80044c549f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000000000009f, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8ceefbafd0 : 0xffffff800451f5cd 
0xffffff8ceefbb020 : 0xffffff8004658b05 
0xffffff8ceefbb060 : 0xffffff800464a68e 
0xffffff8ceefbb0b0 : 0xffffff80044c5a40 
0xffffff8ceefbb0d0 : 0xffffff800451ec97 
0xffffff8ceefbb1d0 : 0xffffff800451f087 
0xffffff8ceefbb220 : 0xffffff8004cc27cc 
0xffffff8ceefbb290 : 0xffffff800464aa3a 
0xffffff8ceefbb410 : 0xffffff800464a738 
0xffffff8ceefbb460 : 0xffffff80044c5a40 
0xffffff8ceefbb480 : 0xffffff80044c549f 
0xffffff8ceefbbd80 : 0xffffff7f879a56d3 
0xffffff8ceefbbe60 : 0xffffff7f879a4a4a 
0xffffff8ceefbbf20 : 0xffffff800464c60a 
0xffffff8ceefbbf40 : 0xffffff80045446c7 
0xffffff8ceefbbf80 : 0xffffff8004544888 
0xffffff8ceefbbfa0 : 0xffffff80044c513e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(222.0)[754827F6-D42B-3311-815E-C3A9E312BEC1]@0xffffff7f879a2000->0xffffff7f879cbfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6317793935850
last loaded kext at 6228508556513: >usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f891a0000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AHV   1
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AHDA  283.15
@GeForce    14.0.0
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.4
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
@nvidia.NVDAStartup 14.0.0
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>eficheck   1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AMuxControl   5.2.4
>!ALPC  3.1
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.6
>!AFWOHCI   5.6.2
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
>!ASMCLMU   212
|IO!BUSBDFU 7.0.5f6
>!UTCKeyEventDriver 255
>!UTCButtons    255
>!UTCKeyboard   255
>!AIR!C 360
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOFireWireIP   2.3.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IOFireWire!F   4.7.5
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>!UMultitouch   264
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    323.1
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSurface  269.11
|IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 422.120.3
|IOBD!S!F   1.8
|IODVD!S!F  1.8
|IOCD!S!F   1.8
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
|IOAHCISerialATAPI  268
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try an SMC / NVRAM/PRAM reset? I say that because the SMC manages the power, sleep/wake, etc. and you have that AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement being referenced in the log.  It's worth a try first.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

It very well could be the RAM. Especially since you've added 3rd party RAM to the system. Mac's have always been picky about RAM since forever. PC motherboards are more forgiving on RAM while Apple has tighter expectations. Even though the RAM may pass x86memtest aggressive scans it might have a slight timing issue that crashes the Mac. Also, mixing different RAM sizes is not recommended. Each of the RAM memory modules should be exactly the same, a matched pair.

Remove whatever 3rd party RAM that you added and see if the panics cease to occur.

The cost of upgrading to 16GB or RAM is under $100 USD for high quality name brand memory.  If the problem goes away when you remove the 3rd party RAM consider replacing both memory SODIMM's with two 8GB ones. It will help with improving performance on your MBP 2012.

If you don't currently have an SSD, consider installing one as that will help even more for performance and the cost has dropped considerably for 2.5" SSDs. You don't specify which MBP 2012 you have and there are four models from 2012 between 13" & 15". But since the MBP Retina 2012 models have the RAM soldered to the system board that means you must have the 2012 model without the Retina screen.  Therefore 2.5" HDD or SSD.

You should be able to get another couple years out of it but you won't be able to upgrade to Big Sur. After about 2-4 years you will run into software applications no longer being supported on Catalina. Perhaps sooner because of the CPU architecture changes coming soon.

But the good news is by late 2021 to 2022 would be an excellent time to buy a new Mac as the new Apple Silicon should be shipping a model or two end of 2020 and 2021 into 2022 refreshing the entire line-up to use Apple's new processors.  Early indications are impressive to say the least.

If you are on a tight budget see if you can find a newer used MacBook Pro. Big Sur will run on any MBP from Late 2013 and up. A MBP 2015 or up would give you a few more years.  Typically Apple removes hardware support at approximately 7 years of age. It is not always the case but more often than not that is how it works out. As you get closer to 10 years more and more software will not work. With all the massive change developers are going through with the Apple Silicon transition that might mean that developers will drop support for older systems sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yes I have tried to SMC Reset multiple times and nothing happened. Of course, I will try using the previous Macbook RAM sticks to see if the stability of the system will return to normal. I have been considering buying a new Macbook but I was waiting on the new Apple chip Macbook devices as I will be using them for programming even more in the near future. Thanks for you advice I will be making the RAM changes and see if anything changes.